# Do you know the website of the journal Ars Combinatoria?

Tags: combinatorics, combinatorial-game-theory, combinatorial-geometry, publishing

1. Do you know the website of the journal Ars Combinatoria? Is this journal still publishing articles? I have a paper accepted in 2018 by this journal, but now I cannot get any news and message from this journal and its editors. This journal and its editorial board disappeared for a long time. Several colleagues have been experiencing the same situation as me.
2. Do you agree that I should resubmit this manuscript elsewhere for publication?

Related links

1. https://www.researchgate.net/publication/328891537
2. https://www.researchgate.net/publication/281146616
3. https://www.researchgate.net/post/Do_you_know_the_web_sites_of_the_journals_Ars_Combinatoria_and_Utilitas_Mathematica_Are_these_two_journals_ceased
4. https://www.linkedin.com/feed/update/urn:li:activity:6873570054856945664
5. https://qifeng618.wordpress.com/2018/11/13/some-papers-published-by-feng-qi-in-ars-combinatoria/

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ars_Combinatoria_(journal)

Comment: On mathscinet the most recent issue shown is at 2020 (153)

Comment: @markvs Thanks, although this message has no help for my situation I currently encountered. It is better to provide some direct proof verifying that the journal is still publishing articles or not. It is best if I can online see and read newest and latest articles published by this journal. It is best for me to see the list of its editorial board. It is best if one of its editors can communicate with me.

Comment: They do not have any volumes published in 2021. The latest is 153 (2020).

Comment: [This MathOverflow question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/371531/5609), from a little over a year ago, cites the url [http://combinatorialmath.ca/ArsCombinatoria/TOC.html](http://combinatorialmath.ca/ArsCombinatoria/TOC.html). However, that domain seems to have become "a website devoted to the mathematical analysis of gambling games".

Comment: Found in wayback [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20200811163040/http://www.combinatorialmath.ca/ArsCombinatoria/)

Comment: The latest issue of Ars Combinatoria appeared in January 2021 on the Web of Science.

Comment: The research-oriented [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net) may have advice; or perhaps [Academia.SE](https://academia.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At https://combinatoire.com/ars/news/journal-resumes-publication/ there is a notice, dated 20 June 2023, saying:

We are pleased to announce that our journal is back in operation after a temporary period of publication suspension. We apologize for any inconvenience caused during this time and appreciate your understanding.

During the suspension, we encountered difficulties in responding to emails, which may have affected our communication with some of you. We sincerely apologize for any unanswered queries or concerns.

If your paper has been accepted for publication during the period of suspension, we kindly request that you submit your accepted article to the following email address: ac@combinatoire.com. Please ensure to include the title of your paper and the corresponding author’s name in the subject line.

Comment: The URL https://combinatoire.com/ars/news/journal-resumes-publication/ doesn't work again, the journal Ars Combinatoria disappears again!

Answer (score 2):

I also submitted a paper on this journal in 2018. It got published in 2020 (volumes 151) and I never got any notification for that. I knew it from my google scholar account last year.
This is the website of the journal that I found
http://www.combinatoire.ca/ArsCombinatoria/index.html

Comment: Did you pay the Article Processing Charge for your paper published in 2018? I didn't pay anything. The website you provided is very useful for me. This site possibly means that the journal Ars Combinatoria is still regularly running. This is a good news for my paper accepted in 2018. Thank you very much.

Comment: As of Dec 15, 2021, the editorial board and managing editors of Ars Combinatoria have resigned. This possibly means that the journal Ars Combinatoria is ceasing. This is a bad news.

Comment: I sent e-mail to earuet@yahoo.com, but no response.

Answer (score 1):

I have found the new website of journal. Please
New website: https://combinatoire.com/ars/
Print ISSN: 0381-7032
New ISSN: 2817-5204

Comment: I can only accept one answer, so I accepted the answer at https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4735814/.

Comment: The URL https://combinatoire.com/ars/ doesn't work once more, so the journal Ars Combinatoria disappears once again!